# sqlite3 update database with "?" - python

Tags: python, sql, sqlite, insert

I have:

database testing.db3
table: mytable
columns: 'name', 'status'

I do:

```
con = sqlite3.connect('testing.db3')
cur = con.cursor()
cur.execute('select * from mytable where status is null')

data = cur.fetchone()
print(data[0])
```

as wanted I receive following result:

```
('Johnny', 'None')
```

Now I am trying to update this line, it works if I do:

```
cur.execute('UPDATE mytable SET status = "Online" WHERE name is "Johnny"')
```

However if I want to update it with '?', it just doesn't work. Any idea why?

```
cur.execute('UPDATE mytable SET status = "Online" WHERE name is ?', data[0])
con.commit()
con.close()
```

Would appreciate any help. Thank you.

Comment: What's the error message? Is it because you insert two parameters, but the `execute` only expects one?

Comment: "sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied." I did select data[0], which is the first value from tuple.

Comment: You mean that `data[0]` has the value "Johnny"? Correct me if I'm mistaken.

Comment: Yes, please see the answer bellow. It's solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
cur.execute('UPDATE mytable SET status = "Online" WHERE name is ?', (data[0], ))
```

`execute` expects a tuple as an input parameter. Therefore, even if you insert only a single value, you should format it as a tuple.

Although in your question you say that `data[0] = ('Johnny', 'None')`, in the comments you indicate that `data[0]` is the first value of the tuple. So I assume the latter one is the case.